# cannot create variadic tuple

Tags: swift

I have following functions

```
func func1(str1: (String...),str: String){ //wrong one error "cannot create variadic tuple"

    }



func func1((str1:String...),str: String){ //wrong one error "cannot create variadic tuple"

    }
```

It shows error "cannot create variadic tuple" when i try to write above code..But it works when i try to change parameter place like  below

```
func func1(str: String,str1: (String...)){ //Right one

    }

func func1(str: String,str1: String...){  //Right one

    }
```

i just changed the parameter place , can anyone help me to understand what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variadic paramter must always be the last parameter of the function. From Swift documentation:

> A function may have at most one variadic parameter, and it must always
>   appear last in the parameter list, to avoid ambiguity when calling the
>   function with multiple parameters.

Comment: ok thanks..can not i use more than one Variadic parameter in single function?

Comment: Can i use Variadic parameter as return type of an function?

Comment: like this  func func2() -> String...{ }

Comment: I guess you cannot. It also would not make sense. You use variadic parameters like arrays in function implementation. Use `func func2() -> [String] {}`